# List of IPv6 Tor exit nodes?

Tags: ipv6

One of my websites has been plagued by posts advertising fake dating sites through Tor exit nodes. The Tor project publishes a list of [exit nodes](https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py) but they contain only IPv4 addresses. Is there any way to fetch IPv6 addresses?

Comment: IPv6 is going to make blacklisting kinda impractical. Imagine I run some exit and my provider gives me an v6 /64. I could exit from anywhere in that whole /64 range. Trying to enumerate them remotely is difficult (imperfect) for v4, for v6 in would be practically impossible, never mind having to store them in some distributed list, which is kept up to date. I don't think it's going to be feasible, you'd be better approaching the problem with some other mechanism, e.g. a captcha.

Comment: I could block your /64, for that matter. There's no difference.

Comment: How do you know and decide what /64's may or may not be exited from? What about the potential collateral damage?

Comment: Anyway, you'd likely need to update [TorDNSEL](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tordnsel.git/tree/TODO#n4), see also [#16947](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/16947).

Comment: @canonizingironize, thanks for the hint to TorDNSEL.

Comment: @canonizingironize The collateral damage should not be that high. ISPs usually give out /64 ranges to clients for SLAAC. And if a hosting provider falls victim, I could not care less.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this?

Comment: I found  no ready-to-use code that identifies IPv6 exit nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Blacklisting is a shot-in-a-leg practice: if you truly think that spammers are using *just* Tor or Darknets - you're wrong. You need to protect your website better with captchas and social network checked logins, not fighting a TCP windmills

Comment: I have captcha, honeypot and a couple of tricks under the sleeve. The positioning of the website makes social login unacceptable.  And I will mercilessly ban all Tor exit nodes as all Tor users I see as a service provider are malicious ones. Iranian dissidents are not my target audience, though.

Comment: Well, then you parse the consensus data and block around 7k+ IP addresses at the same time...

Comment: That sounds interesting. I have no clue what consensus data is, but  blocking 7K+ addresses is totally feasible even with ipset`.

Comment: it's a Tor status monitoring scripts you're after - like [this](https://torstatus.blutmagie.de/) one